# b2 install command does not run

Tags: c++, boost, build, boost-build, b2

I want to install Boost.Build, but if I want to run this command like in the tutorial:

```
D:\boost_1_74_0> ./b2 install --prefix=C:\BoostBuild
```

Then I get this error message:

```
D:/boost_1_74_0/tools/build/src/tools\gcc.jam:164: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: provided command '-w64-mingw32-g++.exe' not found
error: initialized from C:\Users\maxfe\user-config.jam:1
D:/boost_1_74_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:44: in toolset.using from module toolset
D:/boost_1_74_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:1104: in using from module project-rules
C:\Users\username\user-config.jam:1: in modules.load from module user-config
D:/boost_1_74_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:255: in load-config from module build-system
D:/boost_1_74_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:453: in load-configuration-files from module build-system
D:/boost_1_74_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:607: in load from module build-system
D:/boost_1_74_0/tools/build/src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import from module modules
D:/boost_1_74_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
D:/boost_1_74_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

I have installed MinGw-w64.

Can anyone help me with this?

I followed this tutorial: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to edit "user_config.jam", which is in %HOMEDRIVE% or %HOMEPATH%.